# Error when calling a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-function

I have one function that returns all employee IDs
Function definition is like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp()
  RETURNS setof record AS
$func$
begin
    select emp_id from employee_master;
end;
$func$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when i call this function using

```
select * from tmp() as abc(emp_id text);
```

It gives error like

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "tmp" line 3 at SQL statement
```

Please give solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return a rowset from a PL/PgSQL function you must use `RETURN` - in this case, probably `RETURN QUERY`:

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT emp_id FROM employee_master;
```

I don't see the point of having this in a PL/PgSQL function at all, though.

Answer (score 0):

Make the function a [plain SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET) one as in:

```
...
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: It gives error                                                             ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 6:  select emp_name from employee_master;
         ^

Answer (score 0):

It is *much* more practical to declare the actual type of the column instead of the unwieldy `record` type. Assuming `emp_id` to be `integer`, a simple SQL function could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp()
  RETURNS SETOF integer AS
$func$
   SELECT emp_id FROM employee_master
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

However, the error message in your comment does not match the given question. Depending on your *actual* requirements, you would adjust the `RETURN` type.